# Changing stereoscopic render output to "SIDEBYSIDE" with python

Tags: python, rendering, stereoscopy

I managed to change my output to stereoscopic (and fisheye) with this code:

```
bpy.context.scene.camera.data.type = 'PANO'
bpy.context.scene.camera.data.cycles.panorama_type = 'FISHEYE_EQUISOLID'
bpy.context.scene.camera.data.stereo.convergence_mode = 'PARALLEL'
bpy.context.scene.render.use_multiview = True
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.views_format = 'STEREO_3D'
```

But I can't find a way to set the output to `SIDEBYSIDE` instead of single left and right images.

What am I missing?

I want to render the output in the background, but basicly need to do what these settings in the GUI do:

[image: Side By Side rendering settings]

This setting gives me a single image with both L and R output side by side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be set with `bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.stereo_3d_format.display_mode = 'SIDEBYSIDE' = 'SIDEBYSIDE'`.

You can set other properties there too, like `...stereo_3d_format.use_sidebyside_crosseyed`.

For more options, see the [Stereo3dDisplay API documentation.](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/bpy.types.Stereo3dDisplay.html)

Comment: doesn't seem to work. I still get two seperate images. Using these lines: http://pastebin.com/WBVMyfLG

Comment: `views_format` should be set on `bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.views_format`.